# Which 3 marker creates a triangle that contains specified point?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map with ~50 markers on it (Google maps api v3) and I'd like to click a random point and get which 3 markers surrounds it.
I've found **[this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation)** example, but it doesn't really do the thing i want alone.

Here's an image of my markers and what I'm trying to accomplish:
[[IMAGE]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nP62F.png)

According to image;
When I click to red point, the script should return me the coordinates of those 3 markers connected with yellow lines.
Same for blue point and green lines.

It has to be the narrowest, smallest triangle.

I've tried finding closest 3 markers, it works for most situations but doesn't cover all. (Like when there's 3 markers in the same line with a close range.)

Any advice? Thanks in advance!

**Edit**
ps. I can use PHP with ajax calls if it helps.

Comment: Are the markers fixed?

Comment: @davidstrachan I'm printing them as Javascript array with PHP, then looping & putting on map. They might stay fixed for a while but they'll be changed or new ones will be added time to time. I guess the answer is No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it using PHP, by looping all marker coordinates.

First I checked if a point is in the triangle using **[this class](http://assemblysys.com/php-point-in-polygon-algorithm/)**
Then checked if its' area is smaller than the last one.

```
/* 3 foreach loops{ */

$pointLocation = new pointLocation();
$polygon = array($A['y'].' '.$A['x'], $B['y'].' '.$B['x'], $C['y'].' '.$C['x'], $A['y'].' '.$A['x']);
$point = $P['y'].' '.$P['x'];
if(($pointLocation->pointInPolygon($point, $polygon)=='inside' || $pointLocation->pointInPolygon($point, $polygon) == 'vertex'))
// Here I check the area using another function and save this coordinates if this is the smallest triangle. Then it continues to loop

/* } */
```

This is probably not the most efficient way, but unless I find another way, this'll do the job.